# Grid View inside View Pager blocking swipe function

Tags: android, gridview, scroll, android-viewpager

I have a `Grid View` inside a `View Pager` and every thing is working fine, except while swiping the pages if we touch on grid view and swipe, it is not changing the page.

If we touch on the remaining part of the `view pager` only swipe is working.

I tried disabling the touch functionality of `grid view` and also disable `vertical scroll` of the `grid View`, but it doesn't work. Please help me out!

Comment: See if this question's answer helps:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9839569/correctly-detecting-a-swipe-on-a-gridview-placed-inside-a-viewpager-in-android

Comment: @Bret I have exactly same requirement, but I didn't get the answer!

Comment: Sorry I'm not following --- there are 3 answers in that question --- have you tried any of them?

Comment: @ I'm trying Colig answer!

Comment: @Bret I tried Colig solution, It was only moving up not moving down

Comment: The top answer [Kevin] mentions that there was a problem with Colig's solution -- try his solution out to see if it clears up your issue.